# Windows Server Shared Ram for remote desktop users

Tags: windows, memory, memory-usage, windows-server-2016

We want to setup a Windows server with a number of User CALs so that we can work in the cloud.

We wanted to do a minimum of 4 Gigs of RAM per user, but that is quite expensive.

Is it possible to have a users on a shared ram pool?

Comment: `We want to setup a Windows server with a number of User CALs so that we can work in the cloud.` - What does that even mean? - `We wanted to do a minimum of 4 Gigs of RAM per user, but that is quite expensive.` - What workloads/applications will the users be running?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Fair Share Scheduling I believe is on by default on Windows Server, so you should be good to go.

If you want to manage resources you can use Windows System Resource Manager.

But there is no inherent need to configure per-user-RAM-allowances, users that connect to Windows servers are already sharing resources.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to treat and RDS type solution the same as a VDI type solution.  I am not up to date with Server 2016 RDS but up thru Server 2012 R2, you will share resources completely across all users.  This is a cost effective way to enable multiple users a shared resource remotely.  The problems are that any one user can use all of the resources on the RDS server taking performance away from other users.  Also you will be limited to what all you can do graphics wise (AutoCAD, SolidWorks, Adobe Photoshop, etc).  Depending on what the workload of your remote uers are using, RDS may not be the best solution for you.  You might require more of a VDI solution such as VMware Horizon View, Citrix, XenDesktop, etc.

Keep in mind Disk I/O is also the biggest contraint for multi-user systems.  Average users are used to having around 100 IOPS.  Make sure you plan Disk usage appropriately else end users are going to be frustrated with their user experience.